# Showing a series of functions converges to a periodic function.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis, periodic-functions

Let $z = x+iy$ and let $k \in \mathbb{C}$ be a constant.

I am reading a paper from Perelman where he considers the function,

\begin{align*}
\mathrm{f}&:\mathbb{C}\backslash\ D \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}\\[3mm]
&:z \longmapsto \mathfrak{R}[\ln\left(1+\frac{4k^{3}}{(z + k)^{2} (z - 2k)}\right)]
\end{align*}

where $k \in \mathbb{C}$ is a constant and $D$ is a discrete subset of $\mathbb{C}$

Perelma says that that the series converges
$$
\sum_{a,b\ \in\ \mathbb{Z}}\mathrm{f}\left(z + a + \mathrm{i}b\right)
$$
converges to a function, $\mathrm{g}\left(z\right)$, which $\textbf{is}$ $1$-periodic. It is not clear to me whether I have to find this function $\mathrm{g}\left(z\right)$ explicitly in order to show this $1$-periodicity ?. In any case, I am quite at a loss as how to move forward to show the $1$-periodicity and convergence of this series.

By "$1$-periodic", I mean with respect to $x$ and $y$.

$\textbf{EDIT/UPDATE}$: I am now clear on the $1$-periodicity of the series, however it is still unclear to me why this series converges?

$\textbf{EDIT/UPDATE}$: I realised I copied Perelman's function incorrectly, I have since changed this in the text above, also you can see the relevant part of his paper [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKkQ5.jpg).

Comment: If you accept that $g$ does converge, its periodicity can be derived just from the series: the series expansion of $g(z + 1)$ is the same as the series expansion for $g(z)$ where you reindex $a$ as $a-1$ and likewise for $g(z+i)$.

Comment: @shibai Thank you, that was helpful. Any idea how to show the series converges in first place?

Comment: I don't see how that series will ever converge. The problem is that the terms inside the logarithm go to 0, so the logarithm goes to $-\infty$, not to zero, implying divergence. Are you sure you copied the formula correctly?

Comment: @LukasGeyer Yes, I've copied the formula correctly (checked again). And in answer to your concern, does the fact that the series is summed over $\mathbb{Z}$ change your outlook? Namely, the stuff inside the logarithm is never actually zero and (for fixed $z$) doesn't get arbitrarily close to zero either.

Comment: @LukasGeyer I've since edited the post to the original function in the paper, please see the relevant bit in the paper [here](https://imgur.com/a/TxLGwVk)

Comment: Ah, yes, with the additional +1 in the logarithm this does make sense. In fact, @shibai's deleted answer would now work, together with an estimate of the form $|\ln (1+z)| \le C|z|$ for $|z|<1/2$ or such.

Comment: Based on @LukasGeyer's comments, I've revised my answer, so hopefully it's more correct

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: With the edit on the post, I'm undeleting my answer (with corrections thanks to Lukas' comments)

For completeness I'll port my comment to an answer.
First, periodicity comes for free by definition:
$$
g(z+n+mi) = \sum_{a,b\in\mathbb Z}f(z+n+mi+a+bi) = \sum_{a,b\in\mathbb Z}f(z+(n+a)+(m+b)i) = \sum_{a',b'\in\mathbb Z}f(z+a'+b'i) = g(z)
$$
by reindexing with $a' := n+a$ and $b' := m+b$.

As for convergence, we can bound $0\leq\log(1+x)\leq x$ for all $x\geq0$ (indeed, this is equality at $x=0$ and otherwise check their derivatives) and on the other hand $0\geq\log(1+x)\geq2x$ when $-\frac12\leq x\leq0$. For complex $w$, we have $\Re\log (1+w)=\log|1+w|$, so if we assume $|w|\leq\frac12$, then by both triangle inequalities and monotonicity of $\log$ as a real function, we get
$$
-2|w|\leq\log(1-|w|)=\log|1-|w||\leq\log|1+w|\leq\log(1+|w|)\leq|w|
$$
and thus $|\Re\log(1+w)|\leq2|w|$ for all $|w|\leq\frac12$.

In particular, $|f(z)| = \left|\Re\log\left(1+\frac{4k^3}{(z+k)^2(z-2k)}\right)\right| \leq \frac{2|4k^3|}{|z+k|^2|z-2k|} \in O\left(\frac1{|z|^3}\right)$ as $|z|\to\infty$, from which we can see that the series defining $g(z)$ converges absolutely for almost every $z$.

Comment: You wrote $|\Re\log(1+w)|\leq2|w|$, shouldn't it be $\Re\log|1+w|\leq2|w|$ ? Also you wrote $f(z) \leq \frac{2|1+4k^3|}{|z+k|^2|z-2k|}$ but it should be $f(z) \leq 2+ \frac{8|k|^3}{|z+k|^2|z-2k|}$ right?

Comment: I cared about $|\Re\log(1+w)|=|\log|1+w||$ to address absolute convergence, which is why I needed to bound it below and above by $-2|w|$ and $2|w|$.

Comment: Oops, there's no $1+4k^3$ in the numerator anymore... my bad! I added an edit to elaborate the second point. I used the above result with $w=\frac{4k^3}{(z+k)^2(z-2k)}$ since $w\to0$ as $z\to\infty$ so for $z$ sufficiently large I may assume $|w|\leq\frac12$.